# Turn off the ovens! An optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The problem is more abstract, but can be illustrated nicely using ovens. A oven can produce any heat, but is most efficient when it produces $c$ heat. The inefficency increases quadratically as one moves away from the ideal temperature.

For a concretely example imagine we have the following three ovens

$ \hspace{1cm}
    A = 10, B = 15, C = 20
$

The efficiency loss could then be modeled by

$\hspace{1cm}
    E(x,y,z) = g(10, x) + g(15, y) + g(20, z)
$

Where $g$ is given as

$
\hspace{1cm}
g(a, x)
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
    100(a-x)^2/a & \text{if} & x > 0 \\
         0       & \text{if} & x = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$

**The problem** is at which rate the ovens should run to generate the heat $T$.
In other words minimize $E(x,y,z)$ subject to $x + y + z = T$.

Is there some efficient way to achieve this? For 3, I can iterate over them but for 10 this is harder...

Comment: This can be solved e.g. using Lagrange multipliers, although there are more elementary methods too.

Comment: The condition that a oven can be turned off seems to make Lagrange multipliers difficult. I tried that approach but there for 10 ovens for an example there are $2^10-1$ ways the ovens can be on or off. Leading to an impractical large amount of solutions and equations...

Comment: I find it hard to imagine that running an oven *below* its efficient temperature would increase the absolute inefficiency (as opposed to relative inefficiency). So running an oven at temperature 0.00001 would be highly inefficient, whereas running it at temperature 0 suddenly takes all the inefficiency away.

Comment: It is not that hard to imagine. Imagine an old coke oven. If you want to only run the oven to generate a little bit of heat, you still have to place in a whole coke / woodpiece. An similar analogy would be that there is some inital cost to turn it on, eg it has to warmup firstly. The Orthogonal projection does not account for this.

Comment: Initial cost does not explain the discontinuity in the quadratic equation. And if a piece of wood cannot be broken up, you should have a discrete equation. Surely two pieces of wood cannot be cheaper than a single piece of wood?

Answer (score 1):

The inefficiency is a quadratic function of your variables, and the constraint is a hyperplane. By an appropriate (fairly easy) linear transformation the inefficiency is the Euclidean distance of your variable vector to the origin, and then you are minimizing the distance from the origin to a variable point on a hyperplane: the minimum is reached at the orthogonal projection of the origin on the hyperplane.

Comment: Would this also handle the special case when an oven is turned off?

Comment: If that is so important then it should be part of the question instead of remaining hidden in a reply to a comment; but no, this does not handle the unnatural condition that the cost suddenly jumps to a high value when you turn on the oven, only to decrease steeply at the first infinitesimal increase of the temperature. For that discontinuous problem you would have to consider a separate hyperplane for every combination of ovens.

Comment: I think this is not completely fair to the original poster of the question. It follows directly from a careful reading of function $g$.

Comment: @Erwin correction accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with the global MINLP solvers [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron) and [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne).

[image]

The $y$ variables are binary variables indicating if an oven is on or off. I added an implication $y_i=0 \Rightarrow x_i=0$. The other way around is not needed (if $x_i=0$ the objective will make sure $y_i=0$ as that is better).

The option $optcr=0$ sets a tolerance so that global optimal solutions are found, instead of just good solutions.

The results for $T=23$ look like:

```
----     29 PARAMETER T                    =       23.000  heat

----     29 PARAMETER a  ideal temperature

A 10.000,    B 15.000,    C 20.000


----     29 VARIABLE y.L  use oven

A 1.000,    B 1.000


----     29 VARIABLE x.L  temperature oven

A  9.200,    B 13.800


----     29 VARIABLE loss.L  efficieny loss

A 6.400,    B 9.600


----     29 VARIABLE E.L                   =       16.000  total efficiency loss
```

Oven C is turned off here. You can try out Baron and Couenne yourself on [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/). Or if you post some larger data set I am happy to try that.

### Update

I was not completely happy with my model. Indeed we can formulate it as a quadratic model thereby making the model less non-linear. In fact it can be stated as a convex MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) model. This will allow many more solvers to be able to handle this problem. It is a little bit more complex however:

[image]

The idea is to add a slack variable $s$ that is left to float freely when the oven is off ($y_i=0$). In that case the optimizer will choose a zero loss automatically. If the oven is turned on ($y_i=1$) we require that the slack is zero. In that case the correct loss is calculated.

For a compact conic formulation of this problem see [here](http://blog.mosek.com/2016/03/reformulating-non-convex-minlp-as-misocp.html).

Comment: How well do Baron and Couenne scale on larger problems? Are there guarantees on finding the global minimum? (I presume the answers to *both* these questions can't be favourable.)

Comment: They are (deterministic) global solvers so they can give proven optimal solutions. They can find those for reasonable sized problems (very much depends on the model details). Of course for big problems we usually have to rely on local solvers.